# grey screen after building apk

Tags: flutter

I updated the flutter channel, issued Internet permission in the manifest(I saw answers that helped)

I think the problem is related to Expanded, but I'm not sure, in the debug and release works well, after the build stops

````
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
        title: Text('Справочник'),
      ),
      body: ListView.separated(
        itemCount: data.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Container(
              height: 50,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Expanded(
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      child: Text('${data[index].name}', textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FoodByGroup(dataFood: data[index].foods,)));
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
          );
        },
        separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => const Divider(),
      ),
    );
  }
} ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove Expanded from container,The problem is you can't use Expand in child,means that An Expanded widget must be a descendant or parent

**example:**

```
 Expanded(
      child: MyWidget(),
    ),
```

**Row**

```
Row(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: MyWidget(),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child:Text("Text Widget"),
    ),
  ],
)
```

**in Column**

```
Column(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: MyWidget(),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child:Text("Text Widget"),
    ),
  ],
),
```

not like this

```
Container(
  child: Expanded(
    child: MyWidget(),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take good notice of what your terminal is telling you. DO NOT ignore warnings about widget build order, It will work in debug mode most of the time but show you grey screen in release.

The problem here is that you can only use expanded as a direct child of flex widgets. Expanded need flex ancestor so basically these:  Row, Column, or Flex.